# z-coordinate of a point on a line in 3d using python

Tags: python, math, geometry

If I have x,y coordinates for a point on line in 3D and I need to get this z-coordinate using python, how can I do it ?? I have the start point (x1,y1,z1) and end point (x2,y2,z2) of the line in 3D, so any suggestions please ???

Comment: How do you handle if `x1==x2` and `y1==y2`?

Comment: This is more a math question, there is a different forum on stack exchange for this. http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

You can easily setup a parametric equation for the line:

```
x = x1 + (x2 - x1)*t
y = y1 + (y2 - y1)*t
z = z1 + (z2 - z1)*t
```

So given a (x,y), solve this equation for `t`:

```
x = x1 + (x2 - x1)*t
```

so

```
t = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)
```

or

```
t = (y - y1) / (y2 - y1)
```

Now that you know `t`, you can find `z`:

```
z = z1 + (z2 - z1)*t
```

So in Python it would be:

```
def computeZ(p1,p2,x,y):
    x1,y1,z1 = p1
    x2,y2,z2 = p2

    if x2 - x1 != 0:
        t = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)
    elif y2 - y1 != 0:
        t = (y - y1) / (y2 - y1)
    else:
        print "no unique z value exists"
        return 0

    return z1 + (z2 - z1)*t
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to know either the X or the Y value, not both. The equation, if you have an X value, A, would be:

```
((A - x1)*(z2 - z1)/(x2 - x1)) + z1
```

Using this, you can plug in your two initial points and an x and get the new point like so:

```
def get_points(p1, p2, x):
    x1, y1, z1 = p1
    x2, y2, z2 = p2

    new_z = ((x - x1)*(z2 - z1)/(x2 - x1)) + z1
    new_y = ((x - x1)*(y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)) + y1

    new_p = (x, new_y, new_z)
    return new_p
```

Comment: What happens when x2 - x1 is zero?

Comment: By the time I realized I'd forgotten to account for if the line is parallel to a major axis, you already had your answer up, so I decided to leave mine as is and let yours get picked as correct